# Managing QGIS rule-based styling duplicates

Tags: qgis, duplication, rule-based

I am new to QGIS.

When I am using rule based styling, duplicates for some reason show all the matching symbols and not only the first match rule's symbol.

How do I make show only one symbol even if it matches more than one rule?

[image: rules I used]

[image: example]

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you cannot.
To achieve your result (not having overlaps of different symbols) you have to refine your rules to exclude this possibility. Such as:

```
"TOPO"=1 AND "COVER"<> 1
```

For your base symbol (Other), you should use the rule:

```
ELSE
```

Indeed, the way it currently works is useful if you want to superpose information or create more complicated symbolisation and legends.

And, just in case it helps, you can create a hierarchy in the rules, by dragging one (sub) rule over another. For example:
[image]
The *"Diameter" > 250* rule here will only apply to the features in clay (but the symbols will superpose).